# Хранение объектов разных типов без потери

Tags: c++

Есть базовый класс и несколько дочерних.

```
class Base{
    int x,y;
    void Render();
}

class Child: public Base{
    int z;
    void Render();
}
```

есть вектор в котом я хочу их хранить и итерироваться по ним

```
class Panel{
    vector <Base*> vec;
}
```

Если более предметно, то создавая свой GUI, хочу хранить в панеле все добавленные на нее контролы. Может быть я вообще не в том направлении иду?

Comment: При таком способе хранения информация дочернего класса обрезается до базового.

Comment: Вы идете не в том направлении. Если хотите хранить через указатель на базовый класс, то в нем надо сделать виртуальные методы и обращаться к ним без необходимости получать доступ к дочерним классам. Если вам обязательно нужен доступ к дочерним классам, то не надо их хранить через указатель на базовый, запихивайте все в `tuple` например.

Comment: При таком способе как раз не обрезается, но лучше использовать умные указатели

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы можно было работать с объектами производных классов, имея лишь указатель на базовый, тип должен быть полиморфным. А это значит - иметь виртуальные функции. В частности стоит сделать виртуальным деструктор, во избежании проблем при удалении. Но для вашего случая это как минимум `void Render()`, т.е. в базовом классе объявляем так:

```
virtual void Render();
```

А в производных пишем:

```
void Render() override;
```

После этого при обработке указателей из вашего вектора и вызове `el->Render()` будет вызываться правильная версия функции.